# Mongo DB query between dates is taking too long for last 10 days but not for more than 10

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

Below query is giving results with in time frame ::

```
db.getCollection('XXX').find({'id':'YY', 'date' : { 
        $lt: new Date(), 
        $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-15))
      } })
```

but when I run ::

```
db.getCollection('XXX').find({'id':'YY', 'date' : { 
        $lt: new Date(), 
        $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-10))
      } })
```

it is taking too much time. I am using robo 3t to fetch results.

Comment: Can you post your data structure of the DB ?

Comment: Hello Vishal, do you have indexes on this collection ? 
`db.getCollection('XXX').getIndexes()`

Comment: @seddiki Anass - Yes there are indexes on both of the fields

Comment: Utsav:- I cannot share db structure, but to give an idea (json structure)-  {date : xx, yy : [{ [{[{id: value}]}]}]}